# Do I have to upload a document to SharePoint in order to use Versioning Feature?

Tags: 2010, versioning

I have a folder on my desktop with many files. Ideally, I would like to log into SharePoint 2010, and see the items I have in that folder (similar to a page view), AND SharePoint would allow me to turn versioning on for those documents. Is this possible?

I guess what I'm asking is: DO I HAVE TO UPLOAD DOCUMENTS INTO SHAREPOINT in order for versioning to work? And if not, what options do I have?

Thank you in advance,

Pedro

Comment: You can use a version control system, for example: Git, Mercurial, or SVN.

Answer (score 7):

Versioning is a feature available to items stored in SharePoint lists or libraries.  If the content is not stored in SharePoint, the versioning feature is not available.